# Don't use empty/none variables in method/class

Tags: python

I have a class that looks something like:

```
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    df1: pd.Series = None
    df2: pd.Series = None
    df3: pd.Series = None
    df4: pd.Series = None
    df5: pd.Series = None

    @property
    def series_mean(self) -> pd.Series:    
        series_mean = (
            self.df1
            + self.df2
            + self.df3
            + self.df4
            + self.df5
        ).mean()

        return series_mean
```

Generally this could just be done as a function alone, but for this case, let's just assume I do this.

Now, my issue now is, that none of the df's are mandatory, so I could just give it `df1` and `df5`. In that case, the mean doesn't work due to the `None` in the class.

So how do I go about just using the ones that are not None ? And on top of that, is there a way to get how many of them are not None? I mean, if I wanted to do `/ 2` instead of `.mean()` if there is two that are not None.

Comment: Use a list instead of separate variables, and only put as many values into the list as are needed…?

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a tuple instead and filter on `None`. Then you can easily both `sum` and and query `len` from the filtered tuple.

```
from typing import Tuple

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    dfs: Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series, pd.Series, pd.Series, pd.Series] = (None, None, None, None, None)

    @property
    def series_mean(self) -> pd.Series:    
        not_none = tuple(filter(None, self.dfs))
        return sum(not_none) / len(not_none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually need to keep this as five separate variables, which I doubt, you can use `sum` with a generator expression to filter out the none values

```
@property
def series_mean(self) -> pd.Series:
    return sum(
        df for df in 
        [self.df1, self.df2, self.df3, self.df4, self.df5]
        if df is not None).mean
```